# Convert Crystal Reports string to Date format yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Reports formula field that returns a string in the format dd.MM.yy. How do I create a CR formula to convert this to a Date in the format yyyy-MM-dd?

All dates are form the year 2000 and later. I have tried this so far:

```
Date(2000 + right({@formula}, 2), mid({@formula}, 4, 2), left({@formula}, 2))
```

Comment: What is the problem with formula?

Comment: It returns the error "A number, currency amount, date, time, or date-time is required  here." @formula string is 01.02.15

Comment: what is `2000+`? what is the purpose of using this?

Comment: Trying to change the year part of 01.02.15 to 2015. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first convert the text to date and then back to string. That way it is easiest to comprehend the workings of different casts.

```
ToText(DateValue(
    2000 + ToNumber(Split({@formula}, '.')[3]) , ToNumber(Split({@formula}, '.')[2]), ToNumber(Split({@formula}, '.')[1])
), "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

If you get errors with this conversion you might want to make sure the input string is in correct format:

```
If NumericText(Split({@formula}, '.')[1]) and NumericText(Split({@formula}, '.')[2]) and NumericText(Split({@formula}, '.')[3])  Then
    ToText(DateValue(
        2000 + ToNumber(Split({@formula}, '.')[3]) , ToNumber(Split({@formula}, '.')[2]), ToNumber(Split({@formula}, '.')[1])
    ), "yyyy-MM-dd")
Else "Incorrect string"
```

(Tested with CR 2008)

Comment: Ok, added testing for the parts of the input string

Comment: The input string is a parameter from a main report to a sub report. When placed on the report it shows as:  01.01.15 but still getting an error.

Comment: Sorry! Should've tested it the first time. Now those examples work with CR 2008.

Comment: Perfect! Using CR 2011